# PHP readfile return data

Tags: php, wordpress

(my first question on stack, so sorry for errors and/or inaccuracies...)

So : I've developed a Wordpress Theme and I'd like my users to download the attachments of a post. So I created a Zip Archive and use a readfile(). The function is called by link and using a $_GET['zip'] test.

The Problem : `readfile()` returns (i mean **display**) binary characters like this (here I tried to download a test .png file) : �PNG  IHDRp�r�*�  pHYs�� OiCCPPhotoshop ICC profilexڝSgTS�=���BK���KoR
And nothing is downloaded.

Here my code (the readfile part) :

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
if ($zip->open($file_path.$archive_file_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
  exit("cannot open <$archive_file_name>\n");
}
foreach($file_names as $file){
  $zip->addFile($file,$file);
}
$zip->close();
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file_path.$file).'"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_path.$file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file_path.'screenshot.png');
```

I don't know where to search, and it's my first time with zip archive AND readfile()...

Thanks for the tracks (? do we say that? ) !

Comment: What you're seeing there is binary data, which is perfectly expected for outputting a binary file format. Is this *displaying* in the browser instead of *downloading* as it should?

Comment: If you define the content-type depending on the filetype it may fix your issue.

Comment: File name in `Content-Disposition` should be wrapped in commas. There should also be a space between the parameters. `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');`

Comment: 1/ it is displaying indeed, and not downloading as expected. 2/ the content-type doesn't change anything... 3/ content disposition neither... The problem is the same in local or live.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the headers have been sent to the browser? Sometimes, it might not be the case. Turn on error reporting to check.

Comment: OK. I tested the headers... and that are not the good ones that are sent : `array(6) { [0]=> string(24) "X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.26" [1]=> string(47) "X-Pingback: http://localhost/mdlp-db/xmlrpc.php" [2]=> string(38) "Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT" [3]=> string(51) "Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0" [4]=> string(16) "Pragma: no-cache" [5]=> string(38) "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" }`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how exactly but it works now. I added an ob_start() just at the beginning of the function. Thanks for support !

The entire function :

```
if (!function_exists('zipThoseFiles')) {
    ob_start();
    function zipThoseFiles($id){
        if (!function_exists('zipFilesDownload')) {
            function zipFilesDownload($file_names,$archive_file_name,$file_path){
                $zip = new ZipArchive();
                if ($zip->open($file_path.$archive_file_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE )!==TRUE) {
                  exit("cannot open <$archive_file_name>\n");
                }
                foreach($file_names as $file){
                  $zip->addFile($file,$file);
                }
                $zip->close();

                header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
                header('Content-Type: application/zip');
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file_path.$archive_file_name).'"');
                header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
                header('Expires: 0');
                header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
                header('Pragma: public');
                header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_path.$archive_file_name));
                ob_end_clean();
                flush();
                readfile($file_path.$archive_file_name);
                unlink($file_path.$archive_file_name);
                exit; 
            }
        }
        $fileNames = array();
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'numberposts' => null,
            'post_status' => null,
            'post_parent' => $id
        );
        $attachments = get_posts($args);
        if ($attachments) {
            foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
                $fileNames[] = get_attached_file( $attachment->ID );
            }
        }
        $zip_file_name = 'mediasArchive.zip';
        $file_path = dirname(__FILE__).'/';
        zipFilesDownload($fileNames,$zip_file_name,$file_path);
    }
}
```